# MVVM - Show single object data in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a little doubt and would like your help:

I have a simple object, for example:

```
class MyObject : Model.DefaultModel
{
    private string property1;

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return property1; }
        set { property1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Property1"); }
    }

    private string property2;

    public string Property2
    {
        get { return property2; }
        set { property2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Property2"); }
    }

    private string property3;

    public string Property3
    {
        get { return property3; }
        set { property3 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Property3"); }
    }

}
```

I need to show the data of this object in a DataGrid (or other equivalent list), however, show only one object:
[What I need:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9KAO.png)

```
+------------+---------+
| MyObject   |         |
+------------+---------+
| Properties | Values  |
+------------+---------+
| Property1  | Data... |
+------------+---------+
| Property2  | Data... |
+------------+---------+
| Property3  | Data... |
+------------+---------+
```

What I don't want:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|           | Lists     |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Property1 | Property2 | Property3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Data...   | Data...   | Data...   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Data...   | Data...   | Data...   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Data...   | Data...   | Data...   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

In the table that I need to create, the values need to be *associated* with the object.

Would you know how to indicate the way to perform this task?
Any help is appreciated.

---

### EDIT 1:

1. Is it a good option use **IValueConverter** to do it?
2. When the user modifies the data in the table, how can I create an association with my data source?

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it this way, the easiest thing I see is creating a second object that has two fields, "FirstColumn" and "SecondColumn" then create a List/ObservableCollection of this new object bind it to your grind, and populate it from your "MyObject" object like so

`SuggestedObjectList.Add(new SuggestedObject{ FirstColumn = nameof(oldObject.Property1), SecondColumn = oldObject.Property2});`

Make sure the "SuggestedObject" Implements INofityPropertyChanged if you want the grid edit to trigger the event

Comment: Thank for your answer. Ok, to turn my data for data to rows, it is great. But, how to get data when the user modify my table , let's explain better: when the user modify my table, my source object need to be modified too. How get the binding of this table?

Comment: It will be modified. Use a bindingList for Suggested object, subscribe to the ListChange Event, you can get the changed item and convert it back to your own object(or modify you own object)